# Wildcard search in array with regex in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, search

I have a simple PHP array:

```
$array = array('Michael','Marian','Martina');
```

I have the following function to search for string starting with 'mi':

```
$array = preg_grep("/^Mi.*/", $array);
```

1) How to modify the regex to search for any part of the string not just the beginning of the string? For example searching `ar` would return `Marian`

2) How to make it case insensitive? For example searching for `AR` would also return `Marian`

I'm new to regex. Thanks

Comment: Remove the `^` and add the `i` modifier. Also see the PCRE manual entries http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php

Comment: Wow. Any regex tutorial will tell you that. Google much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you change your regex pattern and remove the `^` which specifies it has to be the start of the string. Case insensitivity can be achieved with the `i` modifier.

```
$matching_letters = 'ri';
$array = preg_grep("/{$matching_letters}/i", $array);

// Marian
```

Demo: https://eval.in/151916

**Edit:** you can also remove the `.*`(s) in this case and just match the letters.

For future reference, [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) and [PHPLiveRegex.com](http://phpliveregex.com/) will do you wonders for learning regex.

Comment: Could ask what is the use of the `{}` in the regex?

Comment: it's a PHP construct to insert the variable above - purely for easy of you swapping letters in and out. It's the same thing as doing `"/" . $matching_letters . "/i"`

Answer (score 1):

1) Your regex matches the "start of string" anchor, `^`. To match anywhere, simply remove the anchor.

2) Use the case insensitive modifier. These come after the final slash, and can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php. Example: `$array = preg_grep("/^Mi.*/i", $array);`